# How to Build PMML from Logistic Regression Coefficients

Tags: python, r, logistic-regression, pmml

I built a logistic regression model long time ago, and I have the coefficients. I did not save the model object itself, but just gathered and kept its `beta`s. It looks like this:

```
variables = ['inquiries', 'income', 'credit']
coeffs = [0.25, -0.34, -0.50]
```

As you know, the logistic regression probability is calculated as follows:

```
xbeta = 0.25*inquiries - 0.34*income - 0.50*credit
prob = 1/(1+e^(-xbeta))
```

My question is: **How can I convert these two equations to a PMML/JPMML**, so that when that (J)PMML is invoked by someone else, it can act like a trained logistic regression model, and produce a probability, using input variable values? Can I just write my PMML using a text editor, or are there any built-in Python or R methods to do this efficiently?

I know how to convert a trained scikit-learn model into PMML or a trained R model to PMML; but I don't know how to convert this kind of a *custom function* to PMML.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Create a full-blown PMML generation application (using [JPMML-Converter](https://gmail.com/jpmml/jpmml-converter) library), which reads logistic regression model description from your proprietary text data format files.
2. Create a dummy R (eg. `glm`) or Scikit-Learn object (eg. `LogisticRegression`) manually, and use existing [JPMML-R](https://gmail.com/jpmml/jpmml-r) or [JPMML-SkLearn](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn) libraries for performing R-to-PMML or SkLearn-to-PMML conversion.

The choice between these two options depends on how many times you need to do this job. Option one requires some effort to develop the application, but should be easier and more maintainable long-term. Option two is more like a quick fix.

Anyway, this should give you an idea how to construct a dummy `LogisticRegression` object based on your stored data, and convert it to PMML using the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from skleanr2pmml import sklearn2pmml
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.classes_ = numpy.asarray([<false class label>, <true class label>])
logreg.coef_ = numpy.asarray([<betas>])
logreg.intercept_ = numpy.asarray([<intercept>])
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("classifier", logreg)
])
pipeline.active_fields = ["inquiries", "income", "credit"]
pipeline.target_fields = ["prediction"]

sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "MyArchivedLogRegModel.pmml")
```